# Forecast accuracy: no MASE with two vectors as arguments

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm using the `accuracy` function from the `forecast` package, to calculate accuracy measures. I'm using it to calculate measures for fitted time series models, such as ARIMA or exponential smoothing.
As I'm testing different model types on different dimensions and aggregation levels, I'm using the MASE, mean absolute scaled error, introduced by Hyndman et al (2006, "Another look at measures of forecast accuracy"), to compare different models on different levels.

Now I'm also comparing models with forecast history. As I only have the forecast values and not the models, I tried to use the `accuracy` function. In the function description is mentioned that it is also allowed provide two vector arguments, one with forecast values and one with actuals, to calculate the measures (instead of a fitted model):

> *f: An object of class "forecast", or a numerical vector containing forecasts. It
>   will also work with Arima, ets and lm objects if x is omitted – in which case
>   in-sample accuracy measures are returned.*
>
> *x: An optional numerical vector containing actual values of the same length as
>   object.*

But I was suprised by the fact that all measures are returned, expect the MASE. So I was wondering if somebody knows what the reason is for that? Why is the MASE not returned, while using two vectors as arguments in the `accuracy` function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The MASE requires the historical data to compute the scaling factor. It is *not* computed from the future data as in the answer by @FBE. So if you don't pass the historical data to `accuracy()`, the MASE cannot be computed. For example,

```
> library(forecast)
> fcast <- snaive(window(USAccDeaths,end=1977.99))
> accuracy(fcast$mean,USAccDeaths)
         ME        RMSE         MAE         MPE        MAPE        ACF1 
225.1666667 341.1639391 259.5000000   2.4692164   2.8505546   0.3086626 
  Theil's U 
  0.4474491
```

But if you pass the whole `fcast` object (which includes the historical data), you get

```
> accuracy(fcast,USAccDeaths)
         ME        RMSE         MAE         MPE        MAPE        MASE 
225.1666667 341.1639391 259.5000000   2.4692164   2.8505546   0.5387310 
       ACF1   Theil's U 
  0.3086626   0.4474491
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass objects other than a `forecast` object to get the MASE prediction. For example, I want to use the `vars` package to make predictions and calculate the MASE. See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244506/measuring-var-accuracy-using-accuracy-from-forecast

Comment: Dr. Hyndman. Thanks for your work in time series forecasting. Please evaluate my answer for finding MASE without using 'forecast' class object. It would be great if you could incorporate it within your package as well!

Comment: Dr. Hyndman, is it possible to obtain MASE error metric for test set(ts format) data with actual data?

Answer (score 13):

The paper on MASE clearly explains how to find it (even for non time-series data)

```
computeMASE <- function(forecast,train,test,period){

  # forecast - forecasted values
  # train - data used for forecasting .. used to find scaling factor
  # test - actual data used for finding MASE.. same length as forecast
  # period - in case of seasonal data.. if not, use 1

  forecast <- as.vector(forecast)
  train <- as.vector(train)
  test <- as.vector(test)

  n <- length(train)
  scalingFactor <- sum(abs(train[(period+1):n] - train[1:(n-period)])) / (n-period)

  et <- abs(test-forecast)
  qt <- et/scalingFactor
  meanMASE <- mean(qt)
  return(meanMASE)
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful function +1

Comment: Is there a way to use the function in case i have seasonal data with more than one season? E.g. daily data with a weekday pattern (7) and a yearly pattern(365).

Answer (score 0):

To help myself a little bit, I created a function to calculate the MASE, as described by Hyndman et al in "Another look at measures of forecast accuracy" (2006).

```
calculateMASE <- function(f,y) { # f = vector with forecasts, y = vector with actuals
    if(length(f)!=length(y)){ stop("Vector length is not equal") }
    n <- length(f)
    return(mean(abs((y - f) / ((1/(n-1)) * sum(abs(y[2:n]-y[1:n-1]))))))
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://robjhyndman.com/papers/foresight.pdf
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_scaled_error