# Plotting predicted value and raw score of a time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am now using the "vars" package in R to examine the interrelationship between two time series. Specifically, our data has 66 time points. I divided it into test sample (1-60 observations) and hold-out sample (61-66 observations). I want to plot the predicted value of all 66 observations with the raw score of all 66 observations along the same scale (from 1 to 66) in the same plot to compare the model fit. But I failed to do so with par and layout function. It is highly appreciated if you can kindly give me some instructions on it.

Below is my R code:

```
library("vars")
setwd("c:$temp")  
filename<-"data.txt"
full<-read.table(filename,header=TRUE,sep="\t")
env<-full[1:60,]
varlag1<-VAR(env,p = 2,type = "const");
summary(varlag1)
plot(varlag1)
predict<-predict(varlag1,n.ahead=6,ci=0.95)
list(predict)
raw_v1<-full[1:66,1]
plot(predict,names="v1",lwd=3)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(as.ts(raw_v1),lwd=1)
raw_v2<-full[1:66,2]
plot(predict,names="v2",lwd=3)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(as.ts(raw_v2),lwd=1)
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244506/measuring-var-accuracy-using-accuracy-from-forecast/18298244#18298244)

Comment: Besides appearing to be a duplicate, there is no test data. That should be provided (Useless whitespace edited out.) Sometimes plotting routines use `par` settings internally and override your efforts. "Failed to do so" is not particularly descriptive. Did you get anything?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look as pretty as you might want, but I guess it is something like this you are looking for?

> pred1<-c(env[,"v1"], predict$fcst$v1[,1])
>
> pred2<-c(env[,"v2"], predict$fcst$v2[,1])
>
> pred3<-c(env[,"v3"], predict$fcst$v3[,1])
>
> ts.plot(cbind(pred1,raw_v1), col=1:2, lwd=2)
>
> ts.plot(cbind(pred2,raw_v2), col=1:2, lwd=2)
>
> ts.plot(cbind(pred3,raw_v3), col=1:2, lwd=2)