# Calculate MASE with cross-sectional (non-time series) data in R

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting

I am trying to compute the accuracy of predictions using mean absolute scaled error (MASE) for cross-sectional (non-time series) data in R.  I have a vector of forecasted values and a vector of observed values.  According to Rob Hyndman, [MASE is suitable for non-time series data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108734/alternative-to-mape-when-the-data-is-not-a-time-series).  According to Hyndman's textbook, [for calculating MASE with cross-sectional data, errors should be scaled relative to the mean forecast](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5).  I tried to calculate MASE with the `accuracy()` function of the `forecast` package, which according to [its documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/accuracy), uses the in-sample mean forecasts for scaling errors in non-time series data.  However, [as noted by others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092536/forecast-accuracy-no-mase-with-two-vectors-as-arguments), the `accuracy()` function does not compute MASE with two vectors as arguments because it requires historical data to compute the scaling factor.  If I had time-series data, I could create a forecast object and pass it to `accuracy()`, but I'm not sure how to do this with cross-sectional data.

Here's my attempt to create a function to calculate MASE based on [Hyndman's formula for scaling errors in cross-sectional data](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5):

```
computeMASE <- function(forecast, actual){
  mydata <- data.frame(na.omit(cbind(forecast, actual)))
  n <- nrow(mydata)

  scalingFactor <- mean(mydata$forecast)
  errors <- mydata$actual - mydata$forecast
  scaledErrors <- errors/(sum(abs(mydata$actual - scalingFactor)) / n)

  MASE <- mean(abs(scaledErrors))
  return(MASE)
}
```

Here's a small example:

```
set.seed(33333)
observedValues <- rnorm(1000)
forecastedValues <- observedValues + rnorm(1000, sd=.5)

observedValues[sample(1:1000, 10)] <- NA
forecastedValues[sample(1:1000, 10)] <- NA

computeMASE(forecast = forecastedValues, actual = observedValues)
[1] 0.5147389
```

It's not clear to me that I want to pass a `lm` model to `accuracy()` because my vector of forecasted values contains the forecasted values, not values on a predictor that I'm using to generate forecasted values.  Indeed, when I pass the two vectors as arguments versus as a `lm` model, the accuracy estimates are different:

```
round(accuracy(f=forecastedValues, x=observedValues), 2)
         ME RMSE  MAE    MPE   MAPE
Test set  0 0.51 0.41 -55.62 259.12

round(accuracy(f=lm(observedValues ~ forecastedValues)), 2)
             ME RMSE  MAE    MPE   MAPE MASE
Training set  0 0.44 0.35 -20.87 203.64 0.44
```

My function calculates MASE with the same value as `accuracy()` when passing the predictions from a `lm` model:

```
computeMASE(forecast = predict(lm(observedValues ~ forecastedValues, na.action=na.exclude)), actual = observedValues)
[1] 0.4413931

accuracy(f=lm(observedValues ~ forecastedValues))
                   ME      RMSE       MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set 2.014282e-17 0.4388396 0.3488355 -20.86792 203.6389 0.4413931
```

I have two questions:

1. Is my function correct for calculating MASE with cross-sectional data, according to [Hyndman's formula](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5)?
2. Is there a simpler way to calculate MASE with cross-sectional data using the `accuracy()` function without needing to write a function?

Answer (score 3):

The help file says that it works. Don't you believe it?

```
# Generate some artificial training and test data
x <- 1:100
y <- 5 + .1*x + rnorm(100)
xtrain <- sample(x, size=80)
ytrain <- y[xtrain]
xtest <- x[-xtrain]
ytest <- y[-xtrain]

# Compute forecasts from a linear model
forecast <- predict(lm(ytrain~xtrain), newdata=data.frame(xtrain=xtest))

# Plot training data, test data and forecasts
plot(xtrain, ytrain)
lines(xtest,forecast,col='red',pch=19)
points(xtest,ytest,col='blue',pch=19)

# Compute accuracy statistics
accuracy(forecast,ytest)
```

Both `forecast` and `ytest` are numerical vectors as requested. But MASE will not be produced because the MASE is based on a scaling factor computed from the *training* data. So it makes no sense to ask for MASE if you don't also pass the training data to `accuracy`. The simplest way to do that is to pass the whole forecast object like this:

```
forecast <- forecast(lm(ytrain~xtrain), newdata=data.frame(xtrain=xtest))
accuracy(forecast,ytest)
```

The `forecast` object contains more than just the point forecasts for the future periods. It also contains the training data, uncertainty estimates, and more.

If you don't want to use a `lm` for prediction, then you have to set up the forecast object yourself, containing at least the point predictions (`mean`), the insample fits (`fitted`) and the training responses (`x`). Like this:

```
forecast <- structure(list(mean=rep(10,20), fitted=rep(10,80),
   x=ytrain), class='forecast')
accuracy(forecast,ytest)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Dr. Hyndman. It's not clear to me that I want to pass a lm model to accuracy() because my vector of forecasted values contains the forecasted values themselves, not values on a predictor that I'm using to generate forecasted values. Indeed, when I pass the two vectors as arguments versus as a lm model, the accuracy estimates are different (see my modified question above with a code example demonstrating this).  Basically, I'm looking to pass two vectors, one of forecasts and one of actuals, to obtain MASE.  Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: My code does pass two vectors, one of forecasts and one of actuals.

Comment: When I run your code using forecast v. 6.1, it does not output MASE:  accuracy(forecast,ytest)
                 ME      RMSE       MAE       MPE     MAPE
Test set -0.1854176 0.8635394 0.6957568 -2.760838 7.325117